# What is another word for perspective?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, synonyms, vocabulary

In the sentence:

> This experience gave me a new [perspective].

What would be an eloquent word (or short phrase) that I could use instead of "perspective"?

Comment: How about "point of view"?  (Or maybe you should look in a thesaurus.)

Comment: @HotLicks: I was going to say "viewpoint" and add that bit about the thesaurus as well.

Comment: See what the dictionaries say about the meaning of the word.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The experience gave me a completely new ***angle*** on how I should perceive
>   life in general.

...

> The experience has completely changed my ***outlook*** on life.

...

> The experience was the source of my new ***attitude*** towards life in
>   general, and certain types of people in particular.

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying it changed the way you understand part of our world, see an issue differently than you did before, etc., then "outlook" would work well.